# Validation error after transaction commit

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am working on a node project that uses Sequelize 5.21.5 with MySql 5.5 as database engine.

I have a method that inserts values into a linking table that is used in a many-to-many relationship. There is a unique constraint on the linking table that dictates that the combination of the two id fields must be unique.

[image]

I want to be able to insert multiple entries into the user_levels table at the same time. I tried doing this by using a sequelize transaction. I first add a userLevel with a userId of 1 and a levelId of 9 (does not yet exist) and then I add another one with a userLevel of 1 and a levelId of 8 (which does exist).

I expected the transaction to fail and be rolled back, however the transaction was committed and only the userLevel with levelId of 9 was added and a validation error was thrown for the userLevel with the levelId of 8.

How can I have the transaction fail as a whole and have it roll-backed instead?

```
  updateLevelsForUser = async (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<any> => {
    const userId: number = parseInt(req.params.userId, 10);
    const levelIds: number[] = [9, 8];

    Database.getInstance().sequelize.transaction(async (t) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < levelIds.length; i += 1) {
        UserLevel.create<UserLevel>(
          {
            userId,
            levelId: levelIds[i],
          },
          { transaction: t },
        );
      }
    });
  };
```

Output:

```
Executing (0efdccac-6d93-4434-8ac4-1ff291d65178): START TRANSACTION;
Executing (0efdccac-6d93-4434-8ac4-1ff291d65178): INSERT INTO `user_levels` (`id`,`userId`,`levelId`) VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?);
Executing (0efdccac-6d93-4434-8ac4-1ff291d65178): INSERT INTO `user_levels` (`id`,`userId`,`levelId`) VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?);
Executing (0efdccac-6d93-4434-8ac4-1ff291d65178): COMMIT;
Unhandled rejection SequelizeUniqueConstraintError: Validation error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add **await** before *UserLevel.create*

```
Database.getInstance().sequelize.transaction(async (t) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < levelIds.length; i += 1) {
        await UserLevel.create<UserLevel>(
          {
            userId,
            levelId: levelIds[i],
          },
          { transaction: t },
        );
      }
    });
```